# PHP - Undefined variable and Cannot use isset()

Tags: php, isset

I have a little problem with this code. I always get an **Undefined variable error** message! 
I tried it with the isset but another error!

```
if ((${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]}=="on") && ($row['WORK_MOD']=='n'))
```

> Error: Undefined variable: mm_183 in

```
if ((isset(${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]}=="on")) && ($row['WORK_MOD']=='n'))
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead)

Can you tell me what is the best solution for my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `isset` and equality operators together.

```
if (isset(${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]}) && ${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]} =="on" && ($row['WORK_MOD']=='n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `isset` before testing the var

```
if(isset(${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]}) {
     if (${'mm_'.$row["NODE"]=="on")) && ($row['WORK_MOD']=='n'))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks the quick answer, but I have:
 **syntax error, unexpected '{'**